# is it correct to say, "I like having." as a standalone sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I consider, "I like having," to be the reciprocal action of, "I like giving," which stands alone on its own without much confusion.  In, "I like giving," it is implied that there is some object, wealth, knowledge, etc that is given without having to define it.  Can it also work that one can like "having" implicitly in a broad sense without there being a concrete object in one's possession?

Comment: "Having" isn't the reciprocal of "getting". Its reciprocal is "receiving".

Comment: good point. it's more of the opposite than reciprocal. apart from that, do you see any other issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. The OED records an intransitive meaning for the verb *have*:

> b. *intransitive.* To possess something (as opposed to possessing nothing); esp. to be wealthy.

Some examples of usage:

> <sup>1838   M. F. Tupper Proverbial Philos. (ed. 2) 228   *So shall thou walk in peace, deserving, if not **having.***
>
>   1845   Eclectic Mag. July 380/1   *The great inequality…between the rich and poor, between the numbers of those who
>  
>                                                            **have** and those who **have** not.*
>
>   1937   E. Hemingway (title)    *To **have** and **have** not.*
>
>   2007   E. Charles Daughters of Doge (2008) 144   *There is a very wide gap between those who **have** and those who
>
>                                                                                         **have** not.*</sup>

Comment: Can you replace the image with actual text so that it can be read by the visually impaired and web crawlers?

Comment: @Laurel Done...